# code displaying the wrong output

Tags: java

An Internet Service Provider has three different subscription offers for its customers:

```
• Offer A: For $9.95 per month 10 hours of access are provided. Additional hours are $2.00 per hour 
• Offer B: For $13.95 per month 20 hours of access are provided. Additional hours are $1.00 per hour 
• Offer C: For $19.95 per month unlimited access is provided.
```

Write a program Internet.java that takes the offer the customer has purchased (A, B, or C) and the number of hours that were used. It should then display the total charges.

```
> java Internet A 20
The total charges: $29.95
```

I already wrote my code but for some reason it keeps displaying the wrong output:

```
public class Internet {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        String offer = args[0];
        int hours = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); 
        String error = "error";
        charge(offer,hours);

    }
        public static double charge(String offer, int hours){
            char c = offer.charAt(0);
            double PackA = 9.95;          
            double PackB = 13.95;
            double PackC = 19.95;
        if (c == 'A'){
            PackA = (hours - 10)*2.00;
            System.out.println("the total charges: " + PackA);
            return PackA;
        }
        else if(c == 'B'){
            PackB = (hours - 20)*1.00;
            System.out.println("the total charges: " + PackB);
            return PackB;
        }
        else if (c == 'C') {
            System.out.println("the total charges: " + PackC);
            return PackC;
        }
        return error;

    }
}
```

Comment: use debugger to see what's going on during execution

Comment: What output is it displaying?  what do you expect?

Comment: I don't see how it can possibly display the wrong output as it doesn't compile at all (trying to return `error` from `charge`, a variable that is of the wrong type and not even declared in that scope).

Comment: for example, for the example i provided, (java Internet A 20
The total charges: $29.95), the output is instead "
The total charges: $20"

Comment: @ Soylet Green yes, 29.95 is the correct answer, but instead the output im getting is  20. @Boann i replaced error by 0.

Comment: Not to go on a tangent, but how old is the book (or whatever) this assignment came from? That looks like the pricing structure for AOL from about 1996.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Yeah, I was wondering if there is still anyone around who limits themselves to 20 hours of Internet access per month.  I know people who have trouble limiting themselves to 20 hours per day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the start value of your packs with the result of your calculations.
This:

`PackA = (hours - 10)*2.00;`

will overwrite any existing value in `PackA`.

What you want is this:

`PackA += (hours - 10)*2.00;`

The `+=` operator is shorthand for `PackA = PackA + (hours - 10)*2.00;`
which will include the original value of the offers in your calculation.

Do the same for thing for `PackB`.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you forgot to add the base rate to case A and B.

```
PackA += (hours - 10)*2.00;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to return an undeclared variable named 'error' at the end of your charge function.

Your charge function is also meant to return a double, so returning the string 'error' would not work either.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove Satic from function definition**

```
    public double charge(String offer, int hours)
```